# How do I implement a text box that expands (and collapses) upon a touch

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, user-experience

Thanks for any advice on how to achieve this for a mobile website that runs on all browsers!

Answer (score 0):

you could use css 3d transforms

something like

```
input {
    width: 280px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: width 1s ease;
    transition: width 1s ease;
}

input:focus {
    width: 340px;
}
```